# Pipenv consistently failing to lock and is producing a lot of error output

Tags: python, pipenv, pipenv-install

I am having an issue with using Pipenv that just started recently for some reason.  Pretty consistently it seems that anytime I try to create/install a virtual env from a Pipfile with `pipenv install` I am getting a Locking Failed error, followed by a LOT of output error messages.  I have been trying to work through this, updating `setuptools` and other various packages trying to find where the issue is but am having no luck with solutions to similar problems I have found online so far.

System Specs:
2019 iMac
Big Sur 11.1

Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
fastapi = "*"
fastapi-utils = "*"
uvicorn = {extras = ["standard"], version = "*"}
sqlalchemy = "*"
pytesseract = "*"
pdf2image = "*"
pillow = "*"
cmake = "*"
pandas = "*"
python-multipart = "*"
dataclasses = "*"
psycopg2-binary = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
pypdf2 = "*"
pipx = "*"
spacy = "*"
numpy = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7.9"
```

The output from the error message is below:

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/erbun/Documents/Lambda School/Labs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asylum-ds-a/Pipfile
Using /Users/erbun/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/bin/python3.7m (3.7.9) to create virtualenv...
⠙ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.7.9.final.0-64 in 756ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/erbun/.local/share/virtualenvs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asyl-iMyelADK, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/erbun/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.3, setuptools==51.0.0, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /Users/erbun/.local/share/virtualenvs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asyl-iMyelADK
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
ERROR:pip.subprocessor:Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /Users/erbun/.local/share/virtualenvs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asyl-iMyelADK/bin/python /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-build-env-2gd0gl5f/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.4.1,<7.5.0' 'blis>=0.4.0,<0.8.0' 'numpy>=1.15.0'
     cwd: None
Complete output (75 lines):
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-52.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
Collecting cython>=0.25
  Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
Processing /Users/erbun/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/20/85/35/22c2942bc726e15d643da43c441f83490117d7b06dc7c2e732/cymem-2.0.5-cp37-cp37m-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Using cached preshed-3.0.5.tar.gz (14 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Processing /Users/erbun/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/03/51/93/6a20938381704ae7b6093cc8e9c4ebb09d44579d2c3fa1a26c/murmurhash-1.0.5-cp37-cp37m-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
Collecting thinc<7.5.0,>=7.4.1
  Using cached thinc-7.4.5.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/erbun/.local/share/virtualenvs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asyl-iMyelADK/bin/python /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-build-env-zwryakhp/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'cython>=0.25' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=1.0.1,<3.1.0' 'blis>=0.4.0,<0.8.0' 'numpy>=1.15.0'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (49 lines):
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-52.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
  Collecting cython>=0.25
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Processing /Users/erbun/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/03/51/93/6a20938381704ae7b6093cc8e9c4ebb09d44579d2c3fa1a26c/murmurhash-1.0.5-cp37-cp37m-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
  Processing /Users/erbun/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/20/85/35/22c2942bc726e15d643da43c441f83490117d7b06dc7c2e732/cymem-2.0.5-cp37-cp37m-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl
  Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=1.0.1
    Using cached preshed-3.0.5.tar.gz (14 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Installing backend dependencies: started
    Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
  Collecting blis<0.8.0,>=0.4.0
    Using cached blis-0.7.4.tar.gz (2.8 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/erbun/.local/share/virtualenvs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asyl-iMyelADK/bin/python /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/tmp46jpx0j4
         cwd: /private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-install-_rpx54j6/blis
    Complete output (21 lines):
    init_dgelsd failed init
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 240, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 91, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return hook(config_settings)
      File "/private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-build-env-xww5q9c6/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
      File "/private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-build-env-xww5q9c6/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 130, in _get_build_requires
        self.run_setup()
      File "/private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-build-env-xww5q9c6/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 24, in <module>
        import numpy
      File "/private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-build-env-xww5q9c6/overlay/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError(msg)
    RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
    RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned

    ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/erbun/.local/share/virtualenvs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asyl-iMyelADK/bin/python /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/tmp46jpx0j4 Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/erbun/.local/share/virtualenvs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asyl-iMyelADK/bin/python /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-build-env-zwryakhp/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'cython>=0.25' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=1.0.1,<3.1.0' 'blis>=0.4.0,<0.8.0' 'numpy>=1.15.0' Check the logs for full command output.
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 764, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 760, in main
    dev=parsed.dev)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 741, in _main
    resolve_packages(pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, dev)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 709, in resolve_packages
    requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 692, in resolve
    req_dir=requirements_dir
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1403, in resolve_deps
    req_dir=req_dir,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 1108, in actually_resolve_deps
    resolver.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 823, in resolve
    results = self.resolver.resolve(max_rounds=environments.PIPENV_MAX_ROUNDS)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 180, in resolve
    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 268, in _resolve_one_round
    their_constraints.extend(self._iter_dependencies(best_match))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 383, in _iter_dependencies
    dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 229, in get_dependencies
    legacy_results = self.get_legacy_dependencies(ireq)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 351, in get_legacy_dependencies
    download_dir, ireq, wheel_cache
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 306, in resolve_reqs
    results = resolver._resolve_one(reqset, ireq)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 339, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 287, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 509, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req, self.req_tracker, self.finder, self.build_isolation,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 95, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 38, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._setup_isolation(finder)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 68, in _setup_isolation
    "Installing build dependencies"
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/build_env.py", line 202, in install_requirements
    call_subprocess(args, spinner=spinner)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/erbun/.local/share/virtualenvs/Lambda-School-Labs-human-rights-first-asyl-iMyelADK/bin/python /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2020.11.15/libexec/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/vg/jzyp1_n94pq55jdvv6mtktw40000gn/T/pip-build-env-2gd0gl5f/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'cython>=0.25' 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=3.0.2,<3.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.4.1,<7.5.0' 'blis>=0.4.0,<0.8.0' 'numpy>=1.15.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any help in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: dont use `*` in in defining the package version, if you don't know just leave it as it is. ie instead of `pipx = "*"` use `pipx` only

Comment: The actual error seems to be "*RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.*" Might be related: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15947

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something I also noticed with the BigSur updates. Although there is an active issue for this on GitHub, a work around for the time being is to run the following command before you attempt to lock your Pipfile or install any packages. Note: this will only be effective in the terminal you run this command in.

```
export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1
```

This will allow backwards compatibility and can be tested by running the following command before and after running the export command above

```
sw_vers
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Link to relevant Github issue: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4564